# Which Continuous Integration for Selenium 2 with TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium

So I have a Selenium Automation project (using Maven).
I'd like to be able to set my tests to run overnight and possibly email a report daily to the team.
Which CI would be most suitable for TestNG.xml suites?

I tried Hudson but I couldn't figure out a way to execute TestNG files from the build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Hudson to kick off a Maven job (Hudson has a Maven plugin http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Maven+2+Project+Plugin *works with maven 3*) that runs your test, see http://testng.org/doc/maven.html

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways that you may try and Hudson is one of them. However, you might not find a good resource or article to follow.

Here is a nice walk-through how to succeed - [Continuous Integration with Selenium](http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/continuous-integration-with-selenium/)

I would also recommend to look at [TestNG and Advanced Concepts](http://www.scribd.com/doc/87504616/172/Continuous-Integration) book for a complete reference.